# Replace text strings based on values from a different worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to update a list of URLs in one worksheet based on information in another worksheet.

Sheet1 contains 16 columns. You find URLs to be replaced in column G.

URLs will look similar to this. Basically many different URLs with different language/country folders (chde, usen, dede).

```
|URLs      (Column G)                         | 
|---------------------------------------------|
|https://www.apple.com/chde/iphone-13-pro.html|
|https://www.apple.com/usen/iphone-13-pro.html|
|https://www.apple.com/chde/iphone-se.html    |
|https://www.apple.com/dede/iphone-se.html    |
```

In Sheet2 you will find a mapping table for part of the URLs:

```
|Old                |                    New|
|-------------------|-----------------------|
|/iphone-se.html    |/iphone-seexample.html |
|/iphone-13-pro.html|/iphone-13-protest.html|
```

[image: example]

The code needs to replace the URLs in Column G in Sheet1 based on the mapping table from Sheet2.

Using the examples above the output in Column G should be:

```
|URLs      (Column G)    Updated                  | 
|-------------------------------------------------|
|https://www.apple.com/chde/iphone-13-protest.html|
|https://www.apple.com/usen/iphone-13-protest.html|
|https://www.apple.com/chde/iphone-seexample.html |
|https://www.apple.com/dede/iphone-seexample.html |
```

The list and number of lines in all worksheets vary from week to week.

I tried to understand and adjust code I found online.

Comment: You're more likely to get help here if you shown the code you tried, and explain what problem you had with it.

Answer (score 0):

### Replace Multiple SubStrings in a Range

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ReplaceSubStringsBasic()

    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = Sheet2.Range("A2:B11")
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = Sheet1.Range("G2:G11")
    
    Dim srrg As Range
    For Each srrg In srg.Rows
        drg.Replace srrg.Cells(1).Value, srrg.Cells(2).Value, xlPart, , False
    Next srrg
   
End Sub


Sub ReplaceSubStrings()
' Needs the 'RefColumn' function.

    Const sName As String = "Sheet2"
    Const sFirst As String = "A2"
    
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dFirst As String = "G2"
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    
    ' Destination
    Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets(dName)
    Dim dfCell As Range: Set dfCell = dws.Range(dFirst)
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = RefColumn(dfCell)
    If drg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Source
    Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets(sName)
    Dim sfCell As Range: Set sfCell = sws.Range(sFirst)
    Dim sfcrg As Range: Set sfcrg = RefColumn(sfCell)
    If sfcrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sfcrg.Resize(, 2)
    Dim sData As Variant: sData = srg.Value
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    ' Replace
    Dim sr As Long
    For sr = 1 To UBound(sData, 1)
        drg.Replace sData(sr, 1), sData(sr, 2), xlPart, , False
    Next sr
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
' Purpose:      Creates a reference to the one-column range from the first cell
'               of a range ('FirstCell') to the bottom-most non-empty cell
'               of the first cell's worksheet column.
''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
Function RefColumn( _
    ByVal FirstCell As Range) _
As Range
    If FirstCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
    
    With FirstCell.Cells(1)
        Dim lCell As Range
        Set lCell = .Resize(.Worksheet.Rows.Count - .Row + 1) _
            .Find("*", , xlFormulas, , , xlPrevious)
        If lCell Is Nothing Then Exit Function
        Set RefColumn = .Resize(lCell.Row - .Row + 1)
    End With

End Function
```

Comment: This seems to work as intended, amazing. I have just two questions:

Comment: This seems to work as intended, amazing! I have just two questions.   The Shee2.Range  and Sheet1.Range us line 11 (A2:B11 and G2:G11). Do I need to update and include the exact amount of lines  from Sheet1 and Sheet2 every time?